# RegEx to extract a sub level from url

Tags: c#, regex

i have the following set of Urls:

```
http://test/mediacenter/Photo Gallery/Conf 1/1.jpg
http://test/mediacenter/Photo Gallery/Conf 2/3.jpg
http://test/mediacenter/Photo Gallery/Conf 3/Conf 4/1.jpg
```

All i want to do is to extract the Conf 1, Conf 2,Conf 3 from the urls, the level after 'Photo Gallery' (Urls are not static, they share common level which is Photo Gallery)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to capture what comes after `/Photo Gallery/`, or are you trying to capture `/Conf ?/` wherever it appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for regex.

```
    string testCase = "http://test/mediacenter/Photo Gallery/Conf 1/1.jpg";
    string urlBase = "http://test/mediacenter/Photo Gallery/";

    if(!testCase.StartsWith(urlBase))
    {
        throw new Exception("URL supplied doesn't belong to base URL.");
    }

    Uri uriTestCase = new Uri(testCase);
    Uri uriBase = new Uri(urlBase);

    if(uriTestCase.Segments.Length > uriBase.Segments.Length)
    {
        System.Console.Out.WriteLine(uriTestCase.Segments[uriBase.Segments.Length]);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("No child segment...");
    }
```

Comment: i ended up using a similar solution, but instead of looping through the segments just returned the first segment appears after urlBase

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary to use Regex? You can get it without using  Regex like this

```
string str= @"http://test/mediacenter/Photo Gallery/Conf 1/1.jpg";
var z=qq.Split('/')[5];
```

or

```
var x= new Uri(str).Segments[3];
```

Comment: Using URI is better because that one should parse according to relevant RFC specs.  But the code assumes that input has child segments which if not the case will cause `IndexOutOfRange` exception.  See my post above for more defensive version.

Answer (score 1):

This ought to do you:

```
var s = @"http://test/mediacenter/Photo Gallery/Conf 11/1.jpg";
var regex = new Regex(@"(Conf \d*)");
var match = regex.Match(s);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0].Value); // Prints a
```

Of course, you'd have to be confident the 'Conf x' (where x is a number) wasn't going to be elsewhere in the URL.

This will improve it slightly by stripping off multiple folders (Conf 3/Conf 4) in your example.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"((Conf \d*/*)+)");
```

It leaves the trailing `/` though.

Comment: You probably want to put a leading `/` in that regex so that you don't capture things like `"/reConf 1/"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try a RegEx like this.

```
Conf[^\/]*
```

This should give you all "Conf" Parts of the URLs.

I hope that helps.

Comment: it might help if i have 'conf' appear after /photo gallery/, but the values after /Photo Gallery/ will vary, thanks for answer :)